# Linked List in C programming - unable to run the program

Tags: c, linked-list

I've a question regarding Linked List in C programming.
I written out this code, but I've an runtime error while trying to run the code.
I'm new to C programming, please help.

- Exception thrown at 0x00161A66 in Project1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCCCCCCEC.
- Unhandled exception at 0x00161A66 in Project1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCCCCCCEC.
  Error happen at Insert Thompson

Below is the question that I'm trying to work on. I'm unable to print them out by alphabetical order.

The questions that I'm doing is

```
a) Create a pointer to the start of the list called startPtr. The list is empty.
b) Create a new node of type GradeNode that’s pointed to by pointer newPtr of type GradeNodePtr.
Assign the string "Jones" to member lastName and the value 91.5 to member
grade (use strcpy). Provide any necessary declarations and statements.
c) Assume that the list pointed to by startPtr currently consists of 2 nodes—one containing
"Jones" and one containing "Smith". The nodes are in alphabetical order. Provide
the statements necessary to insert in order nodes containing the following data for
lastName and grade:
"Adams" 85.0
"Thompson" 73.5
"Pritchard" 66.5
```

This is the code:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    int main(){
    struct gradeNode{
    char lastName [20];
    double grade;
    struct gradeNode *nextPtr;
    };

    typedef struct gradeNode GradeNode;
    typedef GradeNode *GradeNodePtr;
    GradeNodePtr startPtr = NULL;
    GradeNodePtr currentPtr = NULL;
    GradeNodePtr previousPtr = NULL;

    GradeNodePtr newPtr;
    if (newPtr != NULL){
        newPtr = malloc(sizeof(GradeNode));
        strcpy(newPtr -> lastName,"Jones");
        newPtr -> grade = 91.5;
        newPtr -> nextPtr = NULL;

    }

    //Insert "Adams"
//previousPtr is NULL, and currentPtr points to the first node in the list.
    newPtr -> nextPtr = currentPtr;
    startPtr = newPtr;


    newPtr = malloc(sizeof(GradeNode));
    strcpy(newPtr -> lastName,"Smith");
    newPtr -> grade = 40.5;
    newPtr -> nextPtr = NULL;

    newPtr -> nextPtr = currentPtr;
    startPtr = newPtr;

    newPtr = malloc(sizeof(GradeNode));
    strcpy(newPtr -> lastName,"Adams");
    newPtr -> grade = 85.0;


//Insert "Thompson"
//previousPtr points to the last node in the list(containing Smith") and currentPtr is NULL
    newPtr -> nextPtr = currentPtr; //or newPtr -> nextPtr = NULL
    previousPtr -> nextPtr = newPtr;

    newPtr = malloc(sizeof(GradeNode));
    strcpy(newPtr -> lastName,"Thompson");
    newPtr -> grade = 73.5;

//Insert "Pritchard"
//previousPtr points to the node containing "Jones" and currentPtr points to the node contaiing "Smith"
    newPtr -> nextPtr = currentPtr;
    previousPtr -> nextPtr = newPtr;

    newPtr = malloc(sizeof(GradeNode));
    strcpy(newPtr -> lastName,"Pritchard");
    newPtr -> grade = 66.5;

    currentPtr = startPtr;
    while(currentPtr!=NULL){
        printf("Lastname = %s\nGrade = %.1f\n\n",currentPtr->lastName,currentPtr->grade);
        currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
    }






}
```

Comment: What error? Runtime or actually compile time? From what line (google for how to use debugger if it is runtime error such as default).

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @hyde I've edited the question

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should make your logic clear.
Here is some tips which you can use.

1. You're not including `stdlib.h` which includes definition for `malloc`. In this case compiler will issue one warning message
2. After creating `newPtr`, you're checking that for `NULL`. It will be initially `NULL` or some garbage value. You're allocating memory only if it is not `NULL` which is not correct
3. You're not linking nodes properly. First formulate your logic in a paper, then try to code it.